# How to I interrupt sleep()

Tags: c, sleep

So, I have a `while(1)` loop with a `sleep(60)` seconds at the end. The problem is, my program can receive an instruction in the meantime, but will have to wait the 60 seconds until it's executed. I've tried with a `handler` and my other program sending a signal `(with kill(daemonid,SIGCONT))`, but it doesn't seep to interrupt `sleep()` (i.e. make it return).

```
void handler(){
  write(1,"bonjour",7);
  alarm(1);
}

/*code blocks irrelevant to the question*/

int main(){
/*reads and opens files*/
  struct sigaction execaction;
  memset(&execaction,0,sizeof(struct sigaction));
  execaction.sa_handler=handler;
  sigaction(SIGCONT,&execaction,NULL);

 while(1){
    pf[0].fd=request_pipe;
    pf[0].events=POLLIN;

    int p=poll(pf,1,timeout);
      
    if(pf[0].revents & POLLIN){
      
      read(request_pipe,&operation,sizeof(uint16_t));

      switch (operation){
        case CLIENT_REQUEST_CREATE_TASK:
            printf("create\n");
            reply_pipe=open(path2,O_WRONLY);
            rep=SERVER_REPLY_OK;
            write(reply_pipe,&rep,sizeof(int));
            taskid=htobe64(0);
            write(reply_pipe,&taskid,sizeof(uint64_t));
            close(reply_pipe);
            break;
        case CLIENT_REQUEST_LIST_TASKS:
            printf("list\n");
            reply_pipe=open(path2,O_WRONLY);
            rep=SERVER_REPLY_OK;
            write(reply_pipe,&rep,sizeof(int));
            close(reply_pipe);
            break;
        default:
            printf(":(");
      }
    }else{
      printf("Timed out\n");
      printf("coucou \n");
    }
      close(request_pipe);
      int t=60;
      sleep(t);
  }
  return 0;
}
}
```

So the program that writes in these pipes, at the end of every option sends a kill signal to this daemon process.I know it writes things well because after a minute it's executed.

So how can I stop `sleep()` in this case if I receive something in the pipe to read (and then restart it at the end of the loop)? I've tried with SIGCONT, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Use a non-blocking method. If 60 secs of processing time will do, try `clock_t target = clock() + 60 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC; while(clock() < target) { /* check for an event that breaks */ }`

Comment: `int p=poll(pf,1,timeout);` <<-- You are not checking the return value `p`. It could be zero or -1.

Comment: I did the while loop and in it i did the same thing where i'd poll the request pipe (and if I had a POLLIN i would just break) but it doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a function that

- receives the number of total seconds to sleep
- breaks down the sleep 60 into 60 sleeps of 1
- loops a variable between 1 and the number of seconds to sleep
- on each iteration of the loop runs the function pointer to check whether the sleep process should continue

And then you can implement a function that checks whether the sleep should be ended and pass this function pointer to the function that handles the sleep along with the number of seconds to sleep.